# Is it possible to extract font & spacing information from a Google Doc or pdf?

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, data-structures, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a 400+ page Google Doc of a poetry anthology, which I want to parse so I can build several reference indices at the end of the doc. I want to extract author names, poem titles, page numbers, and first lines. Each of these is formatted in a unique, consistent way (font size, location on page, spacing, etc.), and it would be easy to parse if I could say "look for this font size" and "read till the new line" and "skip to the next page". I could work with any data structure; I just need to get the doc in its current form *into* one.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe as a Google Doc or maybe if I download it as a pdf or some other form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: If your references are in their own paragraph then you can loop through all paragraphs and use getAttributes() and compare with your style.  But if they are embedded in a paragraph then you need to check each character for your style using Text.getAttribute(offset)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.